# Unable to install XAMPP in windows 10

Tags: xampp, windows-10

When i tried to install xampp in windows 10 64 bit it shows "windows cannotfind -n".
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is it the first time you're installing XAMPP on that machine? If it is, I would suggest to run some cleaning software that searches for unnecessary files and folders, clean them up and then try to install XAMPP again.
I recommend software like:

- AdwCleaner (https://toolslib.net/downloads/viewdownload/1-adwcleaner/)
- Malwarebytes (https://www.malwarebytes.com/)
- CCleaner

Why do I suggest these? I personally use those myself and it often helps solving my problems with installing software.

If you've already installed XAMPP before, uninstall it completely and try to install it again after reboot!